# How to use someClass.android.ts and someClass.ios.ts without errors

Tags: nativescript, tslint, nativescript-angular

I'm using nativescript angular. I have a class called SomeClass that access the native API of iOS and Android separately.

I've written two files:

**someclass.android.ts**

```
export class SomeClass {
    someFunction() {
        if(isAndroid) {
            // do some android specific code
        }
    }               
}
```

**someclass.ios.ts**

```
export class SomeClass {
    someFunction() {
        if(isIOS) {
            // do some ios specific code
        }
    }               
}
```

Now, in **app.component.ts**, I'm using SomeClass like this:

```
import { SomeClass } from './../shared-code/someclass';
```

without .android.ts or .ios.ts, to enable nativescript to pick the right file depending on the running platform.

and then in the code, I user SomeFunction like this:

```
...
const someClass = new SomeClass();
someClass.someFunction();
...
```

With this setting, **everything works perfectly on both iOS and Android**, but I get the following error

> error TS2307: Cannot find module './../shared-code/someclass'.

Do you have any idea how to tell nativescript/tslint to take into account the .android and .ios files and not to display this error?

Thanks

Comment: Add tyepscript declarations in `index.d.ts` file which will expose the methods from someclass.

Comment: I created a subfolder './../shared-code/someClass/' and added index.d.ts exposing the methods in someClass, and copied someclass.android.ts and someclass.ios.ts to it. Still the same error. Can you elaborate on this please?

Comment: In index.d.ts I added this: export declare class SomeClass { someFunction(): void; }
No ts errors, but got the following error when building the app: 

ERROR in ./app/app.component.ts
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve './../shared-code/someclass' in '/src/app/'

Any ideas?

Comment: @Manoj - thanks for your help. I'm writing a detailed solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's the solution:

Alongside *'someclass.ios.ts'* and *'someclass.android.ts'*, create a definitions file and name it **'someclass.d.ts'** (Not index.d.ts). No need to put the files in a separate folder.

In **someclass.d.ts**, `export declare` the class like this:

```
export declare class SomeClass {
    /**
     * someFunction, is a function that does this and that (description)
     */
    someFunction(): void;

}
```

Then, you can use this from another file like this:

In **app.component.ts:**

```
import { SomeClass } from './../shared-code/someclass';
```

Remember to use /someclass without any extensions.
This would solve build and tslint errors.